# Why doesn't this date query work, but a similar one does?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a query to determine how many workdays have been completed. I've already figured out the opposite, which is for days remaining. The queries are identical save for the > and < operators, yet the < operator does not work with the "[wpdatatables](https://wpdatatables.com/)" plugin I'm using. I know I may need to speak with their support about it but I figured I'd ask in case anyone has a clue:

```
SELECT count(calendar.date) AS Workday FROM calendar 
WHERE calendar.is_weekday = 1 AND calendar.is_holiday != 1 
AND year(calendar.date) = year (curdate()) 
AND month(calendar.date) = month (curdate()) AND day(calendar.date) <= day(curdate())
```

Seems simple enough, but the plugin keeps giving me an error saying it's not finding any data, whereas both queries work just fine in Sequel Pro. Do you think it could just be the plugin? Or perhaps there's another way to build the query.

Comment: Not related to your question, but since you have a calendar table anyway, a yearMonth field would simplify queries like this.

Comment: You do not need the extra function calls to `day()`, but I don't think that is causing your issue: `select count(calendar.date) as Workday 
    from calendar 
    where calendar.is_weekday  = 1
      and calendar.is_holiday <> 1
      and year(calendar.date)  = year(curdate())
      and month(calendar.date) = month(curdate())
      and calendar.date <= curdate()`